# What is the formalism used to describe optional arguments called?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, terminology, regular-expressions

Most command line tools have an usage described by using square brackets for optional parts and just writing out required parts (like in regexes) for example:

> foo [opt1[opt2...]] req1 req2 [opt3...]

It alone is not as powerful as regular expressions since it cannot express the language of zero or more ab's nor the language of strings with even number of a's.

Is the format known under a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to a related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242493/linux-unix-man-page-syntax-conventions) point us towards Wikipedia's [page on CLIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface), which under a subsection titled [*Command Description Syntax*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_description_syntax) describes a similar syntax:

> Built-in usage help and man pages commonly employ a small syntax to describe the valid command form:
>
> - angle brackets for required parameters: `ping <hostname>`
> - square brackets for optional parameters: `mkdir [-p] <dirname>`
> - ellipses for repeated items: `cp <source1> [source2...] <dest>`
> - vertical bars for choice of items: `netstat {-t|-u}`

The Wikipedia article has listed the die.net [Linux man page documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/7/man-pages#synopsis) as **one** of its sources, which indeed — under the *Synopsis* section — describes a similar format:

> **SYNOPSIS**
> briefly describes the command or function's interface. For commands, this shows the syntax of the command and its arguments (including options); boldface is used for as-is text and italics are used to indicate replaceable arguments. Brackets ([]) surround optional arguments, vertical bars (|) separate choices, and ellipses (...) can be repeated. For functions, it shows any required data declarations or #include directives, followed by the function declaration

This is all to say, I don't think there is a canonical answer to your question. There are just different (pretty similar) conventions that are documented near their place of use.

To give my twopence's worth, I think Wikipedia's "Command description syntax" or something like "Manpage synopsis format", would be good names for the convention.